# Resolução do jogo Sudoku dando loop infinito em C

Tags: c, loop, matriz, jogos, ciclo-infinito

Possuo o seguinte código em `C`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// Variáveis globais
int jogo_tabuleiro[9][9] = {0};

int func_quadrante(int quadrante, int numero) {
    int retorno_quadrante = 0;
    int linha_inicio, linha_final, coluna_inicio, coluna_final;

    if(quadrante == 0) {
        linha_inicio = 0;
        coluna_inicio = 0;

        linha_final = 2;
        coluna_final = 2;
    } else if(quadrante == 1) {
        linha_inicio = 0;
        coluna_inicio = 3;

        linha_final = 2;
        coluna_final = 5;
    } else if(quadrante == 2) {
        linha_inicio = 0;
        coluna_inicio = 6;

        linha_final = 2;
        coluna_final = 8;
    } else if(quadrante == 3) {
        linha_inicio = 3;
        coluna_inicio = 0;

        linha_final = 5;
        coluna_final = 2;
    } else if(quadrante == 4) {
        linha_inicio = 3;
        coluna_inicio = 3;

        linha_final = 5;
        coluna_final = 5;
    } else if(quadrante == 5) {
        linha_inicio = 3;
        coluna_inicio = 6;

        linha_final = 5;
        coluna_final = 8;
    } else if(quadrante == 6) {
        linha_inicio = 6;
        coluna_inicio = 0;

        linha_final = 8;
        coluna_final = 2;
    } else if(quadrante == 7) {
        linha_inicio = 6;
        coluna_inicio = 3;

        linha_final = 8;
        coluna_final = 5;
    } else if(quadrante == 8) {
        linha_inicio = 6;
        coluna_inicio = 6;

        linha_final = 8;
        coluna_final = 8;
    }

    for(int l_i = linha_inicio; l_i <= linha_final; l_i++) {
        for(int c_i = coluna_inicio; c_i <= coluna_final; c_i++) {
            if(jogo_tabuleiro[l_i][c_i] == numero) {
                retorno_quadrante = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return retorno_quadrante;
}

int func_linha(int linha, int numero) {
    int retorno_linha = 0;

    for(int c = 0; c < 9; c++) {
        if(jogo_tabuleiro[linha][c] == numero) {
            retorno_linha = 1;
        }
    }

    return retorno_linha;
}

int func_coluna(int coluna, int numero) {
    int retorno_coluna = 0;

    for(int l = 0; l < 9; l++) {
        if(jogo_tabuleiro[l][coluna] == numero) {
            retorno_coluna = 1;
        }
    }

    return retorno_coluna;
}

void func_numeros(int numeros_quadrante) { 
    // Preenchendo todo o tabuleiro (quadrante por quadrante)
    int linha_inicio, coluna_inicio, linha_final, coluna_final;
    int quadrante_tabuleiro = numeros_quadrante;
    int numero_novo;

    if(quadrante_tabuleiro == 0) {
        linha_inicio = 0;
        coluna_inicio = 0;

        linha_final = 2;
        coluna_final = 2;
    } else if(quadrante_tabuleiro == 1) {
        linha_inicio = 0;
        coluna_inicio = 3;

        linha_final = 2;
        coluna_final = 5;
    } else if(quadrante_tabuleiro == 2) {
        linha_inicio = 0;
        coluna_inicio = 6;

        linha_final = 2;
        coluna_final = 8;
    } else if(quadrante_tabuleiro == 3) {
        linha_inicio = 3;
        coluna_inicio = 0;

        linha_final = 5;
        coluna_final = 2;
    } else if(quadrante_tabuleiro == 4) {
        linha_inicio = 3;
        coluna_inicio = 3;

        linha_final = 5;
        coluna_final = 5;
    } else if(quadrante_tabuleiro == 5) {
        linha_inicio = 3;
        coluna_inicio = 6;

        linha_final = 5;
        coluna_final = 8;
    } else if(quadrante_tabuleiro == 6) {
        linha_inicio = 6;
        coluna_inicio = 0;

        linha_final = 8;
        coluna_final = 2;
    } else if(quadrante_tabuleiro == 7) {
        linha_inicio = 6;
        coluna_inicio = 3;

        linha_final = 8;
        coluna_final = 5;
    } else if(quadrante_tabuleiro == 8) {
        linha_inicio = 6;
        coluna_inicio = 6;

        linha_final = 8;
        coluna_final = 8;
    }

    for(int l_i = linha_inicio; l_i <= linha_final; l_i++) {
        for(int c_i = coluna_inicio; c_i <= coluna_final; c_i++) {
            numero_novo = rand() % 9 + 1;

            int verifica_quadrante = func_quadrante(quadrante_tabuleiro, numero_novo);
            int verifica_linha = func_linha(l_i, numero_novo);
            int verifica_coluna = func_coluna(c_i, numero_novo);

            if(verifica_quadrante == 1 || verifica_linha == 1 || verifica_coluna == 1) {
                c_i -= 1;
            } else {
                jogo_tabuleiro[l_i][c_i] = numero_novo;
            }
        }
    }
}

void func_tabuleiro() {
    for(int sla = 0; sla < 9; sla++) {
        func_numeros(sla);
    }

    printf("|=================================|\n| - | 1  2  3 | 4  5  6 | 7  8  9 |\n|=================================|\n");

    for(int linha = 0; linha < 9; linha++) {
        if(linha == 3 || linha == 6) {
            printf("|   |---------+---------+---------|\n");
        }

        for(int coluna = 0; coluna < 9; coluna++) {
            if(coluna == 0) {
                printf("| %d |", linha + 1);
            }

            if(jogo_tabuleiro[linha][coluna] == 0) {
                printf("   ");
            } else {
                printf(" %d ", jogo_tabuleiro[linha][coluna]);
            }

            if(coluna == 2 || coluna == 5) {
                printf("|");
            }

            if(coluna == 8)  {
                printf("|\n");
            }
        }

        if(linha == 8) {
            printf("|=================================|\n");
        }
    }
}

main() {
    srand(time(NULL)); // Inicializando função rand

    func_tabuleiro();
}
```

O meu objetivo é de preencher e resolver todo o tabuleiro seguindo as regras do jogo, ou seja, um número (de 1 a 9) não pode se repetir na mesma linha, coluna ou quadrante (3 por 3). Seguindo a minha lógica, era para estar funcionando, porém ele nunca resolve "de primeira" e na maioria das vezes entra em loop infinito. O que eu fiz foi: estou preenchendo quadrante por quadrante, assim posso verificar os quadrantes anteriores podendo evitar o preenchimento da matriz com números repetidos. Então criei três funções, uma para verificar se o número gerado já existe em um quadrante, outra para verificar a linha e a outra para coluna (cada uma retorna 1 se o número existir e 0 se não existir) e utilizo o retorno delas na seguinte verificação:

```
if(verifica_quadrante == 1 || verifica_linha == 1 || verifica_coluna == 1) {
    c_i -= 1;
} else {
    jogo_tabuleiro[l_i][c_i] = numero_novo;
}
```

Na condição acima eu verifico se o número já existe em alguma das áreas (quadrante, linha ou coluna), se o número existir ele decrementa do `for` referente à coluna e se não existir ele adiciona o número na matriz, ou seja, esse loop vai se repetir até ser gerado um número que não exista em nenhuma das áreas.

Estou utilizando o seguinte `for` dentro da função `func_tabuleiro`:

```
for(int sla = 0; sla < 9; sla++) {
    func_numeros(sla);
}
```

O código acima serve para ir preenchendo os nove quadrantes da matriz, quadrante por quadrante e após esse `for` eu apenas desenho o tabuleiro.

Assim como disse anteriormente, na maioria das vezes ele entra em loop infinito, ou seja, preciso recompilar o código várias vezes até ele conseguir gerar o tabuleiro. Abaixo está o resultado do máximo de quadrantes que ele consegue preencher (8) após várias recompilações do código (com o valor `for(int sla = 0; sla < 8; sla++)`), `< 8` porque esse é o máximo que ele consegue, se eu alterar para `< 9`, ou seja, para preencher tudo, ele sempre fica em loop infinito (mesmo re-executando o código múltiplas vezes).

[image: Máximo que consegue preencher]

Como corrigir esse loop infinito para que o tabuleiro/matriz possa ser sempre preenchida da maneira correta logo na primeira execução?

Comment: Bom, eu não entendo a sua lógica, mas há mesmo algum potencial para entrar em loop infinito ai justamente porque você decrementa a variável `c_i `. Esse decremento não faz muito sentido pra mim (você poderia tentar explicá-lo?). Num cenário em que o seu valor acabou de se tornar `n`, por exemplo, esse decremento o faz se tornar `n-1` justamente antes de retornar ao laço - que vai fazer o valor voltar a `n`! Qual é o objetivo disso?

Comment: Outro problema potencialmente grave do seu código é que a escolha dos números é aleatória. Isso faz com que o seu algoritmo não seja determinístico, e por isso possa demorar muuuiiiitooo tempo (e parecer ser um loop infinito mesmo que não seja). Por exemplo, se as chamadas de `rand()` ficarem gerando 3, 7, 9, 3, 7, 9, 3, 7, 9, 3, 7, 9,... o seu algoritmo nunca irá terminar! Se a sua escolha de algoritmo é essa, o mais indicado é você usar uma lista com os números de 0 a 9 e ir removendo os utilizados da lista.

Comment: Então, @LuizVieira, eu utilizo o decremento na variável `c_i` para ele repetir o laço até ele gerar um número inexistente no quadrante, linha ou coluna para assim poder adicionar ele à matriz. Sobre a aleatoriedade, poderia explicar melhor essa lista de números (1 a 9)? Pois gostaria que fosse o mais aleatório possível...

Comment: Bom, se você precisa repetir mantendo o controle da variável `c_i`, deveria *preferencialmente* utilizar um `while` ao invés de um `for`. Como eu disse, há ai um **potencial** para loop infinito, não tô dizendo que é necessariamente o problema. De fato, o problema mais seguramente está na aleatoriedade. O que eu sugeri é você criar uma lista (em C um vetor mesmo serve) com os números de 0 a 9, organizá-los aleatoriamente (leia sobre permutação aleatória e dê uma olhada no último exemplo [dessa página](http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/random.html)) e então ir utilizando-os um a um.

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo de como utilizar o `while`? Pois estou utilizando o `for` para poder inserir o número gerado na posição correta... Em relação à permutação aleatória, devo utilizar ela pela possibilidade do `rand()` gerar números iguais mesmo aleatoriamente?

Comment: Colega, desculpe, esse site não é um fórum. Se vc tem dificuldades em construir um `while`, pode tentar pedir ajuda no [chat]. Sobre o `rand`, é justamente esse o ponto: aleatoriedade não inclui garantia de números diferentes. Se vc utilizar a permutação aleatória, ai *você* garante que os números serão diferentes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu não analisei todo o código para ver se há outros problemas. Mas um potencial problema do seu código é que você faz o seguinte no trecho que faz a tentativa de montar cada coluna/linha (os dois `for` encadeados na chamada de `func_numeros`):

1. Sorteia um número aleatoriamente entre 0 e 9.
2. Procura se o número sorteado já foi utilizado.
3. Se o número sorteado ainda não foi utilizado, utiliza-o (e pula pro passo 5).
4. Se o número sorteado já foi utilizado, volta ao passo 1.
5. Continua o programa...

Bom, o princípio de um sorteio aleatório é que ele é... aleatório! Não há garantia de que você terá sempre números distintos. É uma questão de estatística elementar: todos os números no intervalo do sorteio têm a mesma probabilidade de ser sorteados a cada novo sorteio!

Por exemplo, você faz um sorteio e tira o número 3 (ele tem 10% de chance de ser sorteado, já que o intervalo é de 0 a 9). No próximo sorteio, a chance de tirar o número 3 novamente é: 10%! Tá certo que todos os outros números têm, juntos, 90% de chance de serem sorteados. Mas ainda existe a chance de sair o 3.

> Veja [esse exemplo de código no Ideone](https://ideone.com/ZEAAam) que gera 100 números
>   aleatórios entre 0 e 9. Eu testei uma vez e obtive o seguinte
>   resultado:
>
> **1 7 3 7 4 7 5 9 7 7 4 0 6 0 4 9 3 8 0 2** 6 1 6 6 9 6 4 5 3 1 5 5 8 8 2 2 6 7 2 4 5 6 5 2 7 9 2 0 8 2 3 4 4 9 1 3 6 6 9 9 7 5 4 6 3 6 9 0 4 1 4 0 8 9 2 5 9 4 6 7 6 0 2 1 0 3 4 6 9 4 5 7 9 0 3 3 7 2 3 1
>
> Pode-se observar, em negrito nessas 100 chamadas de exemplo, que foi
>   necessário gerar 20 números (o dobro do necessário!) para que todos os
>   números fossem obtidos (o último foi o número 2). Observe quantas
>   vezes o número 7 foi produzido desnecessariamente.

Assim, esse seu algoritmo essencialmente funciona, mas ele tem um problema grave. Como você sorteia um novo número *sem considerar os que já foram utilizados*, o seu programa pode demorar muito, e esse muito pode ser mesmo tendendo ao infinito (ou ser suficientemente grande para te dar a impressão de que travou em loop). Pode parecer bobagem ou perfeccionismo se preocupar com esse repetições de números em um intervalo tão pequeno (0 a 9), mas se você considerar que o seu algoritmo procura se o número já existe na seção, na linha e na coluna, o custo computacional de fazer a busca por um número já sorteado fica bem caro.

A solução ideal então é que antes de iniciar esses cálculos (o seu laço `for` duplo), você monte uma lista com os números de 0 a 9, sorteie a ordem que eles ficarão (isto é chamado de permutação aleatória) e então vá utilizando um por um, removendo o número utilizado da lista (pode usar uma estrutura de dados de [pilha](http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/pilha.html), por exemplo).

Um exemplo de código que faz permutação aleatória em um vetor é esse:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int randomInteger(int low, int high)
{
    int k;
    double d;
    d = (double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1);
    k = (int) (d * (high - low + 1));
    return low + k;
}

void permutacaoAleatoria(int v[], int n) {
    int r, k, t;
    for (k = n - 1; k > 0; k--) {
        r = randomInteger(0, k);
        t = v[k], v[k] = v[r], v[r] = t;
    }
}

void randomize()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
}

int main() {

    int nums[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    randomize();
    permutacaoAleatoria(nums, 10);
    int i;
    printf("Valores no vetor: [");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%s%d", (i != 0 ? ", " : ""), nums[i]);
    printf("]");
    return 0;
}
```

Ele foi baseado nos exemplos [dessa página](http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/random.html). Veja executando [no Ideone](https://ideone.com/TCz0Ic).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, fiz as mudanças no meu código em relação ao `while` e a permutação, porém agora o erro que ocorre é: ele preenche todo o tabuleiro, mas quando chega em uma posição em que o número não pode ser preenchido ele preenche com lixo e se eu prevenir esse lixo (vindo da `nums[]`) somente o último quadrante é preenchido... Devo criar outra pergunta para o meu problema ou editar a atual?

Comment: Olá Igor. Por nada. Crie outra pergunta. Este site não é um fórum. :) Lembre-se de adicionar na sua outra pergunta os trechos relevantes de código. Ah, e se essa resposta lhe foi útil, por favor considere marcá-la como aceita.